# Array parsing using array value

Tags: php

i have below array,and i have amenities id = 50,i need to show amenities name like 'Express check-out' using amenities id = 50 from this array using php.

```
Array
(
    [amenities] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 0
                    [name] => Cash machine
                    [key] => CASHMACHINE
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 42
                    [name] => Express check-in
                    [key] => EXPRESSCHECKINSERVICE
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 50
                    [name] => Express check-out
                    [key] => EXPRESSCHECKOUTSERVICE
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Wi-Fi
                    [key] => WIFISERVICE
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything or we should write code for you?

Comment: if i tried ['amenities'][2]['name']; i will get the answer...but i dont have key 2 as output...i have only aminity id =50 as input...

Comment: So use `foreach` and check every `id`

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways that your problem can be solved. Easy way can be as follow

```
function getAmenities($array,$id){
    foreach($array['amenities'] as $tmp_arr)
        if($tmp_arr['id']==$id)
            return $tmp_arr['name'];
}

echo getAmenities($array,50);
```

I have not checked result but should work fine. Please let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 0):

How do u create this Array?
Can't u just use the id as the key when u create it, like:

`$key = $array2['id'];
$array['amenities'][$key] = $array2;`